# Nesting functions inside of functions

Tags: python

Is it possible to nest functions inside of functions? If so, what purposes does it have? I have some example code below to show what I mean.

```
def theFunction():
    print "This is a function"
    def functionception():
        print "Bad inception joke...."
```

Once again, is this possible? If so, what purposes does it serve, and how is it used?

Comment: Yup, they're called decorators.

Comment: No. Well, yes, you can do it, but they are not called decorators.

Comment: re closing this question, as someone learning Python I had been wondering about this too, and found the answers useful and concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible, and is frequently used when decorating other functions, for example

```
def memo(f):
    cache = {}
    def func(*args):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = f(*args)
        return cache[args]
    return func
```

Example usage:

```
@memo
def memoized_func(some_arg):
    return some_arg ** 2
```

Here the inner function `func` is used to wrap the argument function `f`, providing additional functionality (in this case saving the results of previous computations).

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can.

You can have the outer function do some boundary condition checks on variables passed to the outer function and pass the "valid/sanitized" variables to the inner function to do the actual processing/manipulation. This is in fact how decorators work.

This blog explains in detail how outer function inner function combination works in decorators - http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/